# JS Exception : animate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I've an image inside a `div`, and the following Javascript code:

```
function animate_down(key1, key2) 
{
   cimage = document.getElementById('sslot_img' + key1);
   var topval = cimage.offsetTop;
   if (topval == -416) {
        cimage.animate({ top: '0px' }, 5000);
   }
   else {
        topval = topval - 32;
        var toptxt = { 'top': topval.toString() };
        cimage.animate(toptxt, 5000);
    }
}
```

I've test it in Firebug, when the debugger reaches `.animate` function it's throwing :

```
cimage.animate is not a function
```

what am i missing?

Comment: probably your code doesn't contain the latest version of jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementById` is not a jQuery function, and will not yield a jQuery object. `animate` is only available on jQuery objects. You need to either wrap your `cimage`:

```
$(cimage).animate( ... )
```

or fetch it through jQuery rather than `getElementById`

```
var cimage = $('#sslog_img' + key1);
```

Note that if you go with the latter option, `cimage` will not have an `offsetTop` property, but rather, you'd have to use

```
cimage.offset().top
```

or

```
cimage[0].offsetTop
```

Comment: The `offsettop` forced me to use getElementById, nice touch, thank you,

Answer (score 2):

`.animate()` is a jquery function, you need to use it on a jquery object.

instead of

```
 cimage = document.getElementById('sslot_img' + key1);
```

use

```
 var cimage = $('#sslot_img' + key1);
```

Comment: or even $(cimage) after you have set cimage

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
cimage = $('#sslot_img' + key1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cimage = document.getElementById('sslot_img' + key1);
```

Is not a jQuery Object.

```
$('#sslot_img' + key1');
```

will return one you can animate.